# How to integrate Parcelables with ORM

Tags: android, sqlite, orm

I'd like to replace the existing caching code in my app (currently done the conventional way using `SQLiteOpenHelper` and custom SQL code) by employing a more maintenance-friendly ORM framework. My app's data model classes implement Parcelable to facilitate sharing between components. Also, they use Jackson annotations. So that probably makes any frameworks using code generation like GreenDAO a non-option?

Other frameworks like ActiveAndroid require subclassing, which doesn't go well with implementing `Parcelable`.

The only framework I've found so far that meets my requirements is ORMLite, which doesn't seem super convenient compared to the other frameworks. Is there any other option out there?

Or alternatively: Is there a maintainable programming pattern that would enable me subclassing a framework-specific super class and still implementing `Parcelable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked out SugarORM's [`SugarRecord`](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/orm/SugarRecord.java) base class. The only member there is a Long, accessible by public getters/setters. I might subclass it and write code that parcels that Long. But there's no guarantee that `SugarRecord`'s layout won't change in the future. I would prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: The above applies to the current dev version. The latest stable release uses a protected field instead.